CentOS 7 no LVM how to expand disk
I have this situation:
root{1}$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0  200G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 1000M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0 38.1G  0 part /mnt/storage
├─sda3   8:3    0   25G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0    1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0    4G  0 part /var/log
└─sda6   8:6    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom 

cfdisk output
I need to expand sda2, how can I do that?

I was in hurry and the only thing that need more space was the backup path of gitlab (I'm trying to move our installation from this old CentOS to a Debian) so I have add a new vDisk and create a soft link, so my 20 GB of backup now have space enought.
Anyway thanks for your replay.
Best regards,
Alessandro
